# Highlight current page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, highlight

So, I'm working on a website and I'm using PHP templates to do it.
I found many tutorials about this but none of them talked about PHP templates.
This is my navigation template:

```
</script>
<!--Main Navigation-->
<header>
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="collapse d-lg-block sidebar collapse bg-dark">
    <div class="position-sticky">
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush mx-3 mt-4">
        <a
          href="index.php"
          class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          aria-current="true"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-address-card fa-fw me-3"></i><span>About us</span></a
          >
        <a href="team.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button">
          <i class="fas fa-users fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Our team</span></a
          >
        <a href="positions.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          ><i class="fas fa-laptop-code fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Open positions</span></a
        >
        <a href="associates.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          ><i class="fas fa-handshake fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Associates</span></a
        >
        <a href="commissions.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          ><i class="fas fa-coins fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Commissions</span></a
        >
        <a href="pingernos.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          ><i class="fas fa-server fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Pingernos</span></a
        >
        <a href="network.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button ntw-item-head"
          ><i class="fas fa-network-wired fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Network</span><i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a
        >
        <a href="badwolf.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button ntw-item">
            <i class="fas fa-paw fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Bad Wolf</span></a
        >
        <a href="mg.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button ntw-item">
          <i class="fas fa-cubes fa-fw me-3"></i><span>MinecraftGolden</span></a
        >
        <a href="cabin.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button ntw-item">
            <i class="fas fa-heartbeat fa-fw me-3"></i><span>The Cabin</span></a
        >
        <a href="haven.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button ntw-item">
            <i class="fas fa-code fa-fw me-3"></i><span>The Haven</span></a
        >
        <a href="credit.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          ><i class="fas fa-award fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Credit</span></a
        >
        <a href="legal.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button"
          ><i class="fas fa-balance-scale fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Legal</span></a
        >
        <!--
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple"
          ><i class="fas fa-money-bill fa-fw me-3"></i><span>Sales</span></a
        > -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Sidebar -->

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark fixed-top">
    <!-- Container wrapper -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Toggle button -->
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-mdb-target="#sidebarMenu"
        data-target="#collapseOne"
        aria-controls="sidebarMenu"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>

    <!-- data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> -->

      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <img
          src="assets/PsychOpsTransparent.png"
          class="navbar-ps"
          height="25"
          alt=""
          loading="lazy"
        />
      </a>
      <!-- Right links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto d-flex flex-row">
        <!-- Icon -->
        <li class="nav-item me-3 me-lg-0">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/PsychOps" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-github bg-button fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navbar -->
</header>
<!--Main Navigation-->

<!--Main layout-->
<main style="margin-top: 58px;">
  <div class="container pt-4"></div>
</main>
<!--Main layout-->
```

How would I be able to highlight the current page?
If anyone knows how to do it, please reply, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: In what way didn't those tutorials work? I don't see why using templates would change the fundamentals of it. And exactly how you should do it depends on what templating engine you're using (they are not all created equal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `REQUEST_URI` or `SCRIPT_NAME` key of `$_SERVER` to get current URL, file and check if it is matched with your link.

##### Option1: Exact match.

First get current URL, file name. Put this code before your menu.

```php
<?php
$thisFile = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] : null));
$thisFile = pathinfo($thisFile,  PATHINFO_BASENAME);
// $thisFile maybe xxx.php one of your file or URL.
?>
```

Next check with your link. This example will use **team.php**, check current URL with that.

```php
<a href="team.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button<?php if (stripos($thisFile, 'team.php') !== false) {echo ' current-menu active';} ?>">
```

The code above will be check for current URL contain team.php. If it is true then classes `current-menu` and `active` will be added.

##### Option 2: Exact match and match file in sub directory.

If your menu have 2 items that use same file name. Example **team.php** and **support/team.php** then use the code below.

```php
<?php
$thisUrl = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] : null));
$thisFile = pathinfo($thisUrl ,  PATHINFO_BASENAME);
?>
<!-- exact match file.php -->
<a href="team.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button<?php if ('team.php' === $thisFile)) {echo ' current-menu active';} ?>">...</a>

<!-- match /path/file.php -->
<a href="support/team.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-2 ripple bg-button<?php if (stripos($thisUrl, 'support/team.php') !== false) {echo ' current-menu active';} ?>">...</a>
```

For both options, you can choose just one CSS class to use as currently active menu item (`current-menu`, `active`) or use your own.

---

##### Add supported CSS.

This is about CSS only. To make your active/current in styled you have to created CSS for them.
Example:

```css
.current-menu {
  border-left: 5px solid #blue;
}
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/3L0byaqf/)

Comment: Ok so, just to get everything right, I have to put the first code in navigation.php at the top  and then add that php script inside the anchor tag in the navbar? And that should do it? So if I then edit in css those class you made (current-menu and active) it should work? Sorry if I ask a lot, but I'm just not used to php.

Comment: Before you add PHP inside `a` tag you can choose just one CSS class. From my example I use 2 classes (`current-menu` and `active`), it's depend on you if you don't use something like Bootstrap you can choose whatever you want. And make sure that you edit `if` condition correctly in each `a`. Then you create new CSS in your file for example `.current-menu {background-color: orange; color: white;}` to style your currently active link.

Comment: Ok, though I'm unsure on what to do with the first code you sent.

<?php
$thisFile = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] : null));
$thisFile = pathinfo($thisFile,  PATHINFO_BASENAME);
// $thisFile maybe xxx.php one of your file or URL.
?>

Comment: It is detect current URL and get only filename for example xxx.php.

Comment: Yeah but, do I just leave it like that or do I have to edit something?

Comment: Leave it. I recommended you to start from the [beginning of PHP here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/).